# ETA panel and Manoeuvres not showing if disconnect and connect CarPlay

Tags: ios, carplay

We have an app with CarPlay support. There you can preview a trip and start it.

However, if we start a trip (see eta and manoeuvres), then turn off the car (or tap disconnect in CarPlay Simulator), then turn it again - CarPlay launched, but there's no eta panel and manoeuvres in it. Even if cancel this trip and start new.

Only after relaunch the app eta and manoeuvres appear again.

Is someone experienced something similar? Maybe this is because some misunderstunding in CarPlay workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out than I've used the same MapTemplate to create new navigationSession after disconnecting and reconnecting InterfaceController - MapTemplate needs to be recreated.